# Is it possible to bind multiple datatables to a listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on a module where i have to create 15 `Datatables` and bind the data tables to a data binding control.

I wanna use `listview` control to bind dt.

Is it possible to bind `multiple datatables` to a `single listview`? All the 15 Data tables contains same columns names.

Comment: What about combining them in stored procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first merge DataTables and then bind the merged datatable to the listview. Something like that:

```
DataTable merged = new DataTable(); 
merged.Merge(table1); 
merged.Merge(table2);
merged.Merge(table3);
//Merge the rest of the data tables.
lvMyList.DataSource = merged;
lvMyList.DataBind();
```